# SQL : Update if exists with stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2005

I need some help with this SQL stored procedure. I’m populating an intermediate table (COM_EXISTENCIAS) with sources from different tables for reporting purposes. In a first step I fill it with the data in COM_INVENTARIOS table that match certain requisites, grouped to sum stocks if there is more than a line matching the cryteria :

```
BEGIN
    INSERT  INTO COM_EXISTENCIAS
            (
              Mes ,
              Anyo ,
              Centro ,
              Codigo ,
              Stock ,
              Descripcion
            )
            SELECT  I.Mes ,
                    I.Anyo ,
                    I.Centro ,
                    I.Codigo ,
                    SUM(I.Stock) AS STOCK ,
                    I.Descripcion
            FROM    COM_INVENTARIOS I
            WHERE   I.Mes = @Mes
                    AND I.Centro = @Emp
                    AND I.NumInv = @NumInv
                    AND I.Anyo = @Anyo
            GROUP BY I.Codigo ,
                    I.Mes ,
                    I.Anyo ,
                    I.Centro ,
                    I.Descripcion
END
```

In a second step, I keep populating the table by using data from another table (only the products that have not been inserted by the first query, or don’t exist already in the table)

```
  INSERT    INTO COM_EXISTENCIAS
            (
              Mes ,
              Anyo ,
              Centro ,
              Stock ,
              Codigo
            )
            SELECT  @Mes ,
                    @Anyo ,
                    @Emp ,
                    0 ,
                    Cod_art
            FROM    COM_ENTRADAS
            WHERE   MONTH(Fecha) = @Mes
                    AND Emp = @Emp
                    AND YEAR(Fecha) = @Anyo
            EXCEPT
            SELECT  @Mes ,
                    @Anyo ,
                    @Emp ,
                    0 ,
                    Codigo
            FROM    COM_INVENTARIOS
            WHERE   Mes = @Mes
                    AND Centro = @Emp
                    AND Anyo = @Anyo
            EXCEPT
            SELECT  @Mes ,
                    @Anyo ,
                    @Emp ,
                    0 ,
                    Codigo
            FROM    COM_EXISTENCIAS
            WHERE   Mes = @Mes
                    AND Centro = @Emp
                    AND Anyo = @Anyo
```

This had been working perfectly as long as I only had to run it once. My issue is sometimes I need to rerun the stored procedure, because some new products have been added to COM_INVENTARIOS. I’m finding that if a line had been already inserted from COM_ENTRADAS in the second step and now exists in COM_INVENTARIOS, instead of updating the current line, it inserts a new line, so I end with two lines with the same data. How should  I modify the first part of the query for updating instead of adding if Mes, Centro,NumInv,and Anyo already exist on the table?

And extra question : After creating the lines, I then do an additional query to update them with the data in COM_ENTRADAS on a third step. It works now, but maybe there is some more "clean" way to query the DB,or joining two queries in one?

```
UPDATE  dbo.COM_EXISTENCIAS
SET     TotEntradas = T.TotEnt ,
        ImporteCompras = T.Importe
FROM    ( SELECT    Cod_art ,
                    ISNULL(ROUND(SUM(Cantidad), 3), 0) AS TotEnt ,
                    ISNULL(ROUND(SUM(( P_coste ) * ( Cantidad )), 2), 0) AS Importe
          FROM      COM_ENTRADAS
          WHERE     Emp = @Emp
                    AND MONTH(Fecha) = CAST(@Mes AS INT)
                    AND YEAR(Fecha) = CAST(@Anyo AS INT)
          GROUP BY  Cod_art
        ) AS T
WHERE   T.Cod_art = dbo.COM_EXISTENCIAS.Codigo
        AND Mes = @Mes
        AND Anyo = @Anyo
        AND Centro = @Emp
```

Comment: You can `UPDATE` or `INSERT` according to conditions with the `MERGE` clause: msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510625.aspx‎

Comment: Forgot to say it's SQL 2005, so I can't use MERGE unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

Well there's a good sql server clause called [`MERGE`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510625.aspx), basic usage pattern looks like:

```
MERGE Table1 AS t
USING 
    (
        SELECT  field1,                           
                ...
        FROM Table2
    ) AS s
    ON t.field1 = s.field1
WHEN MATCHED THEN
    UPDATE 
    SET ...
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
    INSERT
        (                
            ...
        )
    VALUES
        (                
            ...
        );
```

So instead of doing insert and after that update you can do all in a single sql query

Comment: MERGE it's not present for SQL2005, I'm afraid.

Answer (score 0):

This may help you,,,

```
   IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM dbo.COM_EXISTENCIAS WHERE Mes = @Mes ---Proceed your condition)
        BEGIN 
                ----YOUR UPDATE QUERY
        END
    ELSE
        BEGIN
            ---YOUR INSERT QUERY
        END
```

second issue

```
 IF EXISTS 
             (
                SELECT 1 FROM dbo.COM_EXISTENCIAS E INNER JOIN COM_INVENTARIOS I ON I.Codigo = E.Codigo WHERE E.Mes = @Mes and E.Centro=@Emp and E.Anyo=@Anyo 
            ) 

        BEGIN 
            UPDATE dbo.COM_EXISTENCIAS SET Stock = T.Stock 
                 FROM (
                       SELECT Codigo,Stock FROM COM_INVENTARIOS 
                       WHERE Centro=@Emp AND Mes=@Mes AND Anyo=@Anyo and NumInv = @NumInv
                       ) AS T 
                       WHERE T.Codigo=dbo.COM_EXISTENCIAS.Codigo AND Mes=@Mes AND Anyo=@Anyo AND Centro=@Emp 
        END ELSE
```

Comment: Thanks sureshhh. I’ve modified the stored procedure : It worked fine on the first execution (It insered the right registers). However it didn’t worked as intended on a second execution (It didn’t insered a new line, but neither updated the current one). I guess it’s due to not using the “codigo” field (The field for the product code) on the SELECT 1 query. Anyhow, I don’t know exactly how to invoke the Codigo there so it updates only the lines present in COM_INVENTARIOS.

Comment: This is how it looks my procedure now : IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM dbo.COM_EXISTENCIAS WHERE Mes = @Mes and Centro=@Emp and Anyo=@Anyo)
        BEGIN 
               UPDATE  dbo.COM_EXISTENCIAS
    SET     Stock = T.Stock
    FROM
     (SELECT Codigo,Stock
      FROM COM_INVENTARIOS
      WHERE Centro=@Emp AND Mes=@Mes AND Anyo=@Anyo and NumInv = @NumInv)
    AS T WHERE T.Codigo=dbo.COM_EXISTENCIAS.Codigo AND  Mes=@Mes AND Anyo=@Anyo AND Centro=@Emp
        END
    ELSE

Comment: If you consider dbo.COM_EXISTENCIAS.Codigo for updation you have to check that also in the if exists ().or pass @Codigo as parameter.see my edited answer

Comment: I can't pass it as parameter, because I need the procedure to dynamically compare COM_EXISTENCIAS against COM_INVENTARIOS to decide wether if update or insert.(Using the Mes,Anyo,Centro,Codigo fields to compare)

Comment: you have to make your join in if exists (blah,blah...)

Comment: I'm afraid I must be doing something wrong, it keeps updating 0 lines

Answer (score 0):

This is how my query looks right now :

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[COM_GRABA_EXISTENCIAS2] 

@Emp  nchar(3),@Mes nchar(2),@Anyo nchar(4),@MesAnt nchar(2),@NumInv int 
AS  
-- INSTRUCCION DE PRUEBA

 IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM dbo.COM_EXISTENCIAS E INNER JOIN COM_INVENTARIOS I ON I.Codigo = E.Codigo WHERE E.Mes = @Mes and E.Centro=@Emp and E.Anyo=@Anyo) 
        BEGIN 
            UPDATE dbo.COM_EXISTENCIAS SET Stock = T.Stock 
                 FROM (
                       SELECT Codigo,Stock FROM COM_INVENTARIOS 
                       WHERE Centro=@Emp AND Mes=@Mes AND Anyo=@Anyo and NumInv = @NumInv
                       ) AS T 
                       WHERE T.Codigo=dbo.COM_EXISTENCIAS.Codigo AND Mes=@Mes AND Anyo=@Anyo AND Centro=@Emp 
        END 
    ELSE
        BEGIN
                    INSERT INTO COM_EXISTENCIAS (Mes,Anyo,Centro,Codigo,Stock,Descripcion)
                    SELECT I.Mes,I.Anyo,I.Centro,I.Codigo,SUM(I.Stock) as STOCK,I.Descripcion
                    FROM COM_INVENTARIOS I
                    WHERE I.Mes=@Mes and I.Centro=@Emp and I.NumInv = @NumInv
                    GROUP BY I.Codigo,I.Mes,I.Anyo,I.Centro,I.Descripcion
        END
```